# Scrolling UICollectionView causes UITableView in parent UIView to push Collection View out of Frame

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation

My app has a small `UIView` that hides behind the `UINavigationBar`.  I have a gesture recognizer set up that when the nav bar is tapped, this 'popover' `UIView` drops down into view, and the `UITableView` below it drops down to make room for it.  This works well, but when I try to swipe through the collection view to load new cells, the table view pushes the lowered view back up behind the nav bar.

[image: GIF]

I have tried to put and lldb watchpoint on the popover view and table view to see if I could track the view frame change, but I could never seem to hit the watchpoint:

```
(lldb) w s v self->_drawerView->_layer
Watchpoint created: Watchpoint 3: addr = 0x7feac410b788 size = 8 state = enabled type = w
    watchpoint spec = 'self->_drawerView->_layer'
    new value: 0x00007feac410b850

(lldb) w s v self->_tableView->_layer
Watchpoint created: Watchpoint 2: addr = 0x7feac6008008 size = 8 state = enabled type = w
    watchpoint spec = 'self->_tableView->_layer'
    new value: 0x00007feac4102cf0
```

Here is my animation code.  I have put in breakpoints and know that this code is not causing this bug.

```
- (void)toggleDrawer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.6f initialSpringVelocity:0.5f options:0 animations:^{
        if (lowerDrawer) {
            self.drawerView.frame = CGRectMake(self.drawerView.frame.origin.x, self.drawerView.frame.origin.y + 70, self.drawerView.frame.size.width, self.drawerView.frame.size.height);

            // lower table at same time
            self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y + 70, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height - 70);

            // flip arrow
            self.arrowImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

            lowerDrawer = NO;

        } else {
            self.drawerView.frame = CGRectMake(self.drawerView.frame.origin.x, self.drawerView.frame.origin.y - 70, self.drawerView.frame.size.width, self.drawerView.frame.size.height);

            self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y - 70, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height + 70);

            // flip arrow
            self.arrowImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 180);

            lowerDrawer = YES;
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //
    }];
}
```

How should I even begin to debug this?  Is there anything I can do to insure a collection view does not change its frame when loading new cells?

Comment: I would scan the code for anything else that may adjust `tableView.frame`. Also, do you have any auto-layout constraints?

Comment: I didn't have any constraints, but unchecking Use Auto Layout in the Storyboard's Interface Builder Document settings in the File Inspector worked!  I can't believe this, I spend hours trying to debug this last night.  Thanks you!  If you write this as and answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done. Glad you were able to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a conflict between the coordinates manually set by you and the coordinates automatically set by the Storyboard file.

Try checking for any auto-constraints you may have, or uncheck "Use Autolayout" in your Storyboard Interface Builder.